OSError: libtorch_cuda_cpp.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
I needed to have Python torchaudio library installed for my application which is packaged into a Docker image.
I am able to do this easily on my EC2 instance easily:
pip3 install torchaudio
python3
Python 3.10.12 (main, Nov 20 2023, 15:14:05) [GCC 11.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import torchaudio
>>> torchaudio.__version__
'2.2.1+cu121'

But not through my Dockerfile, here's what I have in my Dockerfile:
RUN pip3 install --target=/opt/prod/lib/python3.8/site-packages torchaudio

but when I entered into the docker container started from this image:
>>> import torchaudio
/opt/prod/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torchaudio/_internal/module_utils.py:99: UserWarning: Failed to import soundfile. 'soundfile' backend is not available.
  warnings.warn("Failed to import soundfile. 'soundfile' backend is not available.")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/prod/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torchaudio/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from torchaudio import (  # noqa: F401
  File "/opt/prod/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torchaudio/_extension.py", line 135, in <module>
    _init_extension()
  File "/opt/prod/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torchaudio/_extension.py", line 105, in _init_extension
    _load_lib("libtorchaudio")
  File "/opt/prod/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torchaudio/_extension.py", line 52, in _load_lib
    torch.ops.load_library(path)
  File "/opt/prod/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/_ops.py", line 852, in load_library
    ctypes.CDLL(path)
  File "/opt/prod/python3.8/lib/python3.8/ctypes/__init__.py", line 373, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: libtorch_cuda_cpp.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory


Sorry, forgot to add one note, I cannot use conda in my Dockerfile for other reasons...

I prefer to have a separate requirements.txt for installing Python packages rather than specific pip install commands in the Dockerfile.
 Dockerfile (Upgrading pip is not necessary but it silences a warning message.)
FROM python:3.10.12

COPY requirements.txt .

RUN pip install --upgrade pip && \
    pip install -r requirements.txt

 requirements.txt
torch==2.2.1
torchaudio==2.2.1
numpy==1.26.4



Thanks for this solution, I tried it using a personal Dockerfile this way, it worked well for me as well. But not for my work Dockerfile which still fails with an odd error, I think there's something special with the dependency management inside my organization which doesn't apply elsewhere, thanks.

Do you want to add the odd error to your original question? Or is it the same error?

it's the same error, thanks.

To help further you're going to need to actually provide the Dockefile that's causing the problem. Please add it in your question (or at least a minimal Dockerfile that can be used to reproduce your problem).

It's our internal dependency management system, I cannot post here, to update, we decided not to use this way: package torch into the existing Dockerfile which isn't compatible for our internal dependency issues, your proposed solution definitely works as I tried out in a clean Dockerfile, thanks.

Great. Glad to know that it worked for you. Please would you accept the answer.
